# How to add multiple columns between each column?

Tags: excel, vba

My code adds one column after each existing column.

I need to add 14 columns. I want this to start by adding the columns after column 2 for each column with data. I believe my current code covers that.

```
Dim z As Integer
Columns(2).Select
For z = 2 To 20
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
Next z
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome.... Your code inserts 19 columns.. As you have selected second column First column is inserted between A and B. Now if you want to insert first columns between B and C then Select third column first. and then Z from 4 to 17..Oh you mean 14 columns each time after col B?

Comment: the help on changing first column between B and C is helpful but yes i need to insert 14 columns each time, any ideas?

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 2):

Loop backwards, and no need to [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

This doesn't check if there is any data in the column.

```
Sub x()

Dim z As Long

For z = 20 To 2 Step -1
  Columns(z).Resize(, 14).Insert
Next z

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use SJR's code its more efficient just change it to For z = 21 To 3 Step -1 ... My answer is also edited

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.... Your code inserts 19 columns.. As you have selected second column First column is inserted between A and B. Now if you want to insert first columns between B and C then Select third column first. and then Z from 4 to 17..Oh you mean 14 columns each time after col B? Then...

```
Dim z As Integer
  Columns(3).Select
  For z = 4 To 22
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13)).EntireColumn.Insert
    'ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
  Next z
```

Comment: So this would add 14 columns between each existing, do i need  to change the offset if im doing this 19 times

Comment: You can use SJR's code its more efficient just change it to `For z = 21 To 3 Step -1` ... My answer is also edited

Comment: Naresh - suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: @SJR .. yes,, thats why I suggested the user to use your code. Its more efficient... Thanks for the link.